# get status and edit query limit in Java Client for Google Maps Services

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want geocode some addresses using [Java Client for Google Maps Services](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-java)
My code:

```
private static GeoApiContext context = new GeoApiContext.Builder()
                .apiKey(API_KEY)
               .queryRateLimit(50)
                .build();
private static String geocode(String address) throws InterruptedException, ApiException, IOException, JSONException {
        GeocodingResult[] results =  GeocodingApi.geocode(context,
                address).await();
        String latLong = "";
        if(results != null) {
            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
            latLong = gson.toJson(results[0].geometry);
            String latitude = "";
            String longitude = "";
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(latLong);
            JSONObject location = jsonObject.getJSONObject("location");
            latitude = location.getString("lat");
            longitude = location.getString("lng");

            latLong = latitude + "," + longitude;
        }
        return  latLong;
    }
```

I have two problems:

1. I want get status if i try geocode invalid address since now if i try it i get `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0`, so i want check status of geocode to avoid this exception.
   For exaple I get this exeption for this request:

   {
   "results" : [],
   "status" : "ZERO_RESULTS"
   }
2. I want geocode faster but when i even set queryRateLimit(15000) it run the same slow as before.

So:

1. How get status of geocoding addres or avoid ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.
2. How can I geocode addresses faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find method to check the status in [JavaDoc](https://googlemaps.github.io/google-maps-services-java/v0.2.5/javadoc/) of this library, but you can avoid an exception if you also check that an array of results is not empty. Something like `if(results != null && results.length > 0) {...}` should work for you.

```
private static GeoApiContext context = new GeoApiContext.Builder()
           .apiKey(API_KEY)
           .queryRateLimit(50)
           .build();
private static String geocode(String address) throws InterruptedException, ApiException, IOException, JSONException {
    GeocodingResult[] results =  GeocodingApi.geocode(context,
            address).await();
    String latLong = "";
    if(results != null && results.length > 0) {
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
        latLong = gson.toJson(results[0].geometry);
        String latitude = "";
        String longitude = "";
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(latLong);
        JSONObject location = jsonObject.getJSONObject("location");
        latitude = location.getString("lat");
        longitude = location.getString("lng");

        latLong = latitude + "," + longitude;
    }
    return  latLong;
}
```

The Maps API Standard plan is limited to 50 QPS, you cannot set more. If you need a higher quota you have to purchase a Premium plan with additional QPS.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/usage-limits

**UPDATE**

I have figured out how to get status using the Java Client library. Please note that method `await()` of GeocodingApiRequest can throw `ApiException`.

https://googlemaps.github.io/google-maps-services-java/v0.9.1/javadoc/com/google/maps/errors/ApiException.html

`ApiException` has subclases for each possible status (e.g. OverQueryLimitException, ZeroResultsException, UnknownErrorException, etc.)

You can rewrite you code as the following in order to get status

```
String status;
try {
    GeocodingResult[] results =  GeocodingApi.geocode(context,
            address).await();
    status = "OK";
} catch(InvalidRequestException e) {
    status = "INVALID_REQUEST";
} catch(NotFoundException e) {
    status = "NOT_FOUND";
} catch(OverDailyLimitException e) {
    status = "OVER_DAILY_LIMIT";
} catch(OverQueryLimitException e) {
    status = "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT";
} catch(RequestDeniedException | AccessNotConfiguredException e) {
    status = "REQUEST_DENIED";
} catch(ZeroResultsException e) {
    status = "ZERO_RESULTS";
} catch(UnknownErrorException e) {
    status = "UNKNOWN_ERROR";
}
```

I hope this answer is useful!

Comment: The update does not work in 2021. I just tried making a request that returns NOT_FOUND but the exception is not caught.